# Is payment instruction needed after checkout?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-research, checkout, payment

I work for charity app project and want to know about your opinion with checkout flow.

So this project's potential users are people with 20 - 40 y.o

Im curious what if i don't show payment instruction in the end of checkout flow/summary page. Is the user will confused?

Comment: What do you mean by "payment instruction"?

Comment: I mean, when the user select payment method and we show step by step how the payment method works. I mean what the user must do to pay the bill with selected payment method

Answer (score 1):

I think collecting online donations should be easy, affordable and transparent. Showing payment-related FAQ/instructions at the end of the page will make sense.

Comment: Thank you for the insight

Answer (score 1):

If the donation method needs explanation, maybe you have to consider one that doesn't.

If it's not avoidable, then the user might be given a choice between showing and hiding the payment instruction.

Comment: Thank you for the insight too